# Twitter localization: Single tweet with both an English version and a Japanese version

Tags: twitter, localization

My product's Twitter followers come from various countries.
Some want to read tweets in Japanese, others prefer English, etc.

I usually post a tweet in Japanese immediately followed by its translation in English. Not optimal.

I could split into several Twitter accounts, but that would mean more overhead work. That would also mean less followers (which for many people is a mean of measuring popularity, like it or not). A global account is definitely better.

**QUESTION:** Can I localize a tweet?
The same tweet, with both Japanese version and English version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you can't.**

Your best solution is to have accounts for each language, and to use a Twitter client which supports multiple accounts. You say that this means less followers but honestly, it's better to have *some* followers that actually read and like the content you post than having *a lot* of them that don't even look at your tweets since your constantly spam them with tweets in languages they can't understand.